# In Angular, how do you check if a form (or its elements) have changed in value?

Tags: angularjs, forms, input

I'm aware of properties like `$pristine`, `$dirty` etc. However, `$dirty` simply indicates if that form element has been interacted with.

How do I check if that form element has been actually *changed?*

I need something like a `$changed` property on the element that indicates if the value of that `input` (or in the case of a `form`, any child `input`) has been updated. If the value is set back to the original value, I want `$changed` to be set back to `false`.

My question: does angular have something like this already? If not, how do I go about building such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store the form data, watch and then compare. This directive seems to that does that with a "modified" property which sounds like your "changed" property you are looking for. They have a plunker to test.

You could use a watch but if you want to re-use the code repeatedly you will need to create a directive to do the heavy lifting.

https://github.com/betsol/angular-input-modified

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$watch` like so:

In your controller:

```
$scope.$watch('myForm', function(){
 console.log('Form Changed')
},true)
```

In your HTML:

```
<form name='myForm'>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new name" ng-model="myForm.inputText" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Other" ng-model="myForm.inputOther" />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: This does not handle the scenario if the input was changed to something new and then the user reverted to the original data. Your solution is no better than $dirty.